# error while drawing a pspicture in latex

Tags: pstricks, preview, ghostscript

I get the following error while trying to draw a `pspicture` in LaTeX

GPL Ghostscript

9.15: **** Could not open temporary file ''

What I write inside the compiler is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-eps}

% preview must come after any pstricks package!
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\PreviewBorder=0pt\relax
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\begin{document}

\psscalebox{1.0 1.0}
{
    \begin{pspicture}(0,-2.4)(4.8,2.4)
    \pscircle[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](2.4,0.0){2.4}
    \pscircle[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](2.4,0.0){1.6}
    \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas why I get this? Should I add some other packages? I am using TeXStudio.

Comment: No error here. I get two concentric circles, tightly fitted within the page borders.

Comment: how did you run your example?

Comment: @AlexG I know it works because I also tried it on another machine and it worked perfectly! It should be something related to my laptop! I am now trying to discover the problem!

Comment: Add `\listfiles ` at the top of the document source and compile on the different machines. Then compare the file list at the end of the log files, in particular the package versions.

Answer (score 2):

Well the error comes from **Ghostscript** so its not likely that anything you do in LaTeX will have a lot of effect.

A quick grep through the source reveals that this error occurs in the platform-dependent code, so the exact reason depends on what operating system you are using (you haven't said). But generally speaking it means what it says, Ghostscript tried to open a scratch file, and wasn't able to.

The message should have included the path and name of the file it was trying to open, which you haven't quoted. The most obvious thing to do to start with is look at the directory that GS was trying to use, and check that it exists and is sensible. Then make sure that you (or the process executing GS) has permissions to write in that directory.

Comment: Actually it is not an error! At the end, it says that "Process exited normally" but the result is a blank white PDF! My OS is windows7! BTW, it does not mention any address or directory which I can check!

Comment: The fact that the process exited normally doesn't mean anything, all that tells you (I think) is that Ghostscript dint' seg fault or anything. PostScript/PDF errors will be flagged to stdout, but the process will still exit normally. What version of Ghostscript are you using ? As far as I can see the only way to get nothing on the end of the string (ie no filename) is if you have

Comment: @hmd.pouya: again, it is important to know how you run your document? `xelatex`, `pdflatex`, or ....

Answer (score 1):

rant mode

OK so someone locked or deleted my previous answer 'because it doesn't provide an answer'. Real helpful 'samcarter', what am I supposed to do to help this chap ? Did you read what I said at the top of the post ? I **can't** post a comment, because I don't have sufficient reputation, and if I post an answer asking him questions it gets deleted because it isn't an answer, how do you suggest I work on this ?

I started answering this back when it was on Stack Overflow where I *do* have plenty of reputation. All that's happened so far is that the migration and curation has made it harder and harder for me to provide any assistance. Please, either change your moderation, migrate this back to Stack Overflow where I can at least comment on it, or at the least stop deleting my answers.

Note that the KenS that posted the original answer is the same Ken Sharp that posted the second and now third one. I have no idea where that 161 reputation came from nor why I can't just use my Stack Overflow account, but I can't and I'm not going to jump through hoops trying to sort this out just because someone (erroneously) thought this question fit better on this site.

/rant mode

Now, to continue trying to help hmd.pouya; if you run Ghostscript from the command shell with either gswin32c --help or gswin64c --help (depending on whether you have installed the 32 or 64 bit version) it will *tell* you its version.

I didn't say check 'temp' I said check 'TEMP' by which I mean the Windows environment variable, you can do that from the command shell too with ECHO %TEMP%, you might like to do the same with TMP as well. Check that these are present and point to valid directories.

Comment: I've converted the other 'answer' to a comment on your earlier answer. The site mods can't 'fix' multiple accounts, the network staff can. Contact them and you should be able to 'connect' the two and thus be able to comment here.

Comment: BTW, to me the question looks OK here (certainly within the more general scope): whether it was also on-topic for the main site I'll leave to the mods there.